# What is the difference between Elastic API keys under organization and Stack Management API keys

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

There are two places in **Elastic cloud** where I can see **API keys**:

- `https://cloud.elastic.co/account/keys`, and
- `https://<elastic-cloud-deployment>/app/management/security/api_keys`

What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

Api keys from the Cloud UI are to perform operation on deployments.

- Scale, restart, get billing ... [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-restful-api.html)

Api keys from the deployment are to perform operation within a deployment.

- Create a document, search index ... [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rest-apis.html)